Trying to reduce Column A by 10% and then replace the old numbers in Column A with the new numbers
So I have almost zero knowledge of custom functions in Google Sheets. But I am trying to take the numbers in each cell in Column A, reduce it by 10%, then replace the old numbers with the new reduced number.
I.E. A1 is currently at 100, in a different cell call it B1 =(A1*(1-.1)), and then have the result in B1 replace the number in A1.
function Decay()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var numAdd = numRange.getValue();
  numRange.setValue(numAdd *(1-0.1));
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}

This works, but now I want to make it change every number in a Column, not just in one cell, how can I modify it to do that?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is an inherent issue that is not considered. As described the process is a one-off adjustment, but a formula will would create an infinite loop. That is, it will keep adjusting the value of Column A indefinitely. This question suffers from the XY problem - that is, a focus on a given solution rather than on considering the actual problem. I don't think a custom function is the best solution. A different approach would be to write a script to do a one-off adjustment for a column of values, and trigger the script manually from a custom menu.

It's not clear what you mean by "custom function". In Google Apps Script docs, more specifically in the guides to Extend Google Sheets, a custom function refers to a Google Apps Script function used in a formula. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions.
Custom functions can't use SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValue and any other method that changes the spreadsheet. They are limited to returning a value or an array of values.
If the function is run directly, i.e., by selecting a custom menu option, SpreadsheetApp.flush(); it is not required. It will only make your function take longer to finish. This could be a problem if you call the function using a trigger due to the daily total run time quota for triggers.
Regarding how to change every value on column A, your script should

Read the column A values. Use SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues, method.
Calculate all the new values. You will need to know how to handle arrays in JavaScript. The best options might be methods like Array.prototype.map and Array.prototype.reduce.
Write all the new values at once using SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues


Thank you @Wicket for responding. The code I have posted above works. I use a button function to apply it to the active cell. What I'm trying to do is when i press the button instead of just the active cell changing, every cell in Column A changes also.

@TerryPoole Thanks for the additional details. I updated my answer just before reading your comment. Please remember that all the relevant information should be included in the question body, but you should be careful not to invalidate answers. If you need to post details that will invalidate an answer, post a new one instead of editing the question.

Thank you again, and I apologize, I haven't asked a question here since undergrad so I'm out of practice, and this 24 hour crash course on google scripts has got my brain a bit frazzled.

@TerryPoole No problem. Key things to remember: Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as a programming language. When working with Google Sheets, you will need to know how to handle nested arrays, more specifically, 2D arrays. You might benefit from taking a crash course about "vanilla" JavaScript, specifically the lessons related to arrays. I liked the JavaScript course from Freecodecamp.

I'll go check it out, I am fairly fluent, in MatLab and Python so I just dove in expecting skills to cross over.
